# change the background color without change the header of the gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I have create this code to change the color of row if item of endTimeStamp row equal to "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000" it change the row but also change the header I wan to ask how can I target the item row without the header

```
protected void gv_timesheet_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //To check condition on date time 
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "endTimeStamp")) == Convert.ToDateTime("0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000"))
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add condition - based on `DataControlRowType.DataRow`

```
 if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
      //To check condition on date time 
     if (Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "endTimeStamp")) == Convert.ToDateTime("0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000"))
     {
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     }
  }
```