# gridview first row cel text

Tags: c#, gridview

I have gridview like this in which i am fetching data from database and it have no header column

[image]

this gridview have no header these are rows only.Now Problem is that i want to format that column in which

here u can see `31 DEC` is monday so i want to format the each column in which date is monday.I want to change color of that column which monday in first row .So any one can tell me the idea to do this in c#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608414/change-the-background-color-without-change-the-header-of-the-gridview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153579/set-gridview-row-background-color-using-value-in-binding-dataset

Comment: Sir I dnt Want to fix the column while i want to fix the monday in first cells

Comment: you want to get the day by given date in Cell?

Comment: Actually Dates in First row r being changed dynamically not fixed so i want to format the all columns dynamically where i find the column value as monday

Comment: Please check below answer by @Jignesh.Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Own Answer as like this

```
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells) {
                    if (cell.Text != "-1" && cell.Text != "Cotton Arrival") {

                        char[] c = new char[7];
                        c = cell.Text.ToCharArray();

                        string datee = c[0].ToString()+c[1].ToString() ;
                        string monthh = c[2].ToString() + c[3].ToString();
                        string yearr = c[4].ToString() + c[5].ToString() + c[6].ToString() + c[7].ToString();

                        DateTime dtime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yearr),Convert.ToInt32(monthh),Convert.ToInt32(datee));

                        string day = dtime.DayOfWeek.ToString() ;

                        if (day.ToLower() == "monday") 
                        {
                            GridView1.Columns[count].ItemStyle.CssClass = "monday";
                            GridView2.Columns[count].ItemStyle.CssClass = "monday";
                            GridView3.Columns[count].ItemStyle.CssClass = "monday";
                            GridView4.Columns[count].ItemStyle.CssClass = "monday";
                            break;
                        }
                        count ++;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

This Should Help You To Color You Matching Cell

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    //Check your condition here
    //Get Id from here and based on Id check value in the 
    //underlying dataSource Row Where you have "Done" column Value
    // e.g.
    // (gridview.DataSource as DataTable), now you can find your row and cell 
    // of "Done"
    If(Condition True)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red  // your color settings 
    }
   }
}
```